# How to send the OAuth request in Node

Tags: node.js, oauth, module

I want to access the WS REST API in node.js. I have the `oauth_consumer_key` and the `oauth_token` and the API end point. The oauth_signature_method is HMAC-SHA1.

How to send the OAuth request in Node?

Is there a module/library to generate the request headers? What I expect is a function like:

```
var httprequest = createRequest(url, method, consumer_key, token);
```

---

- UPDATE 10/14/2012. Adding the solution.

I'm using the code below.

```
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth;

consumer = new OAuth('http://term.ie/oauth/example/request_token.php',
                    'http://term.ie/oauth/example/access_token.php',
                    'key', 'secret', '1.0',
                    null, 'HMAC-SHA1');

// Get the request token                    
consumer.getOAuthRequestToken(function(err, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, results ){
    console.log('==>Get the request token');
    console.log(arguments);
});


// Get the authorized access_token with the un-authorized one.
consumer.getOAuthAccessToken('requestkey', 'requestsecret', function (err, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, results){
    console.log('==>Get the access token');
    console.log(arguments);
});

// Access the protected resource with access token
var url='http://term.ie/oauth/example/echo_api.php?method=foo&bar=baz';
consumer.get(url,'accesskey', 'accesssecret', function (err, data, response){
    console.log('==>Access the protected resource with access token');
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We use https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth

Comment: this npm module definitely needs more documentation or at least some notes / comments about what each piece is. I know OAuth is a standard, but different providers require / expect different things depending on who the provider is and what service you want to access. His link to the examples is also dead. very frustrating and disappointing for anyone who doesn't know exactly what to do in OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a complete node twitter package that seems streamlined and useful.
https://npmjs.org/package/twitter

Comment: useless without token_request which is either not there or not documented